# I have Acer F5-573G-59V4 Laptop i want to dual boot it (Windows + Ubuntu), Help me with the procedure to dual boot it..?

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu, kubuntu, lubuntu, acer

How to do dual bootable installation for Acer F5-573G-59V4.

Answer (score 0):

The link given by @Terrance above should help you prepare your hard disk to accept Ubuntu, and there are several other websites that deal with it, so I won't go into that here.

Apart from the important requirements to make sure that `Secure Boot` is disabled in your BIOS/UEFI, and to make sure that `Windows fast start-up` is disabled, Acer BIOS/UEFI **has an extra menu only accessible if you set a supervisor password**. Acers are notoriously difficult to install Linux on.

Follow these steps :

They assume that you have already installed  Ubuntu and it won't boot, but might also be required for booting from a Live USB

1. Make sure your UEFI is up to date.
2. In UEFI, you must set a supervisor password. Once the supervisor password is set, some new menus are accessible.
3. Enter the "Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing" menu. It will allow you to declare the newly installed Ubuntu boot image as trusted on your laptop.
4. Select EMMC >> EFI >> Ubuntu and select the file shimx64.efi. You will be prompted to give it a name of your choice (which will appear in the F12 boot options).
5. Type the name press Enter and then "Yes" should be highlighted.
6. Press enter again. Restart the computer without any boot disk and tap F12 during the boot process.
7. You should now get the boot option menu with the name you chose.
8. You can change the boot order in UEFI now so that it boots directly to the Grub screen.
9. Either disable the supervisor password, or save it in a secure place.